# how to unlock table only for someone table in mysql?

Tags: mysql

When I use mydumper to backup mysql data, mydumper will start a read-only transaction with 'START TRANSACTION WITH CONSISTENT SNAPSHOT', and in this transaction, when backing up a table, a shared read lock will be added to the table, and finally the read lock will be released at the end of the transaction. If I have tens of millions of tables, the dictionary data of all opened tables will be stored in memory and may not be released until the end of the transaction，and this will cause two risks：

1. mysql may have the risk of OOM every time I use mydumper backup;
2. shared read lock added to the table will block the DDL statement;

Therefore, I want to minimize the impact of mydumper backups on mysql, including memory usage and blocking DDL statements, while free memory remains the same.

For example, in the read-only transaction of mydumper, every time a table is backed up, the shared read lock of the table is actively released, so that the memory can be released by using Innodb's dictionary elimination mechanism, and the ddl statement of the table can not be blocked.

My question is, how can I actively release the read lock or write lock of a certain table, similar to 'unlock table t1 read, t2 write'? I know that 'unlock tables' can release all locks in the session, but I only want to release the read/write lock of a certain table, so it is not what I want. So I'm wondering how can I do this?

That's all, thank you everyone!

Comment: You should clarify if you want to modify the mysqldumper (source) code or your own. Also note that "start transaction" is not compatible with (un)lock table. Also, you cannot use unlock (or anything else) to unlock a lock set by a different session (e.g. you cannot unlock a table in your code if it is locked by mysqldumper) - that's the whole point of a transaction: you (you being e.g. mysqldumper) want a consistent state, and if anyone outside of the transaction can just end it for you, you are sad (cause you may wanted to reuse the table after you backuped it up).

Comment: Sorry, I really didn't make it clear. As you said, I really want to modify the source code of mysqldumper or mydumper. And i know that a lock in a transaction cannot be released by other external statements. I would like to ask, if I start a transaction, can I actively release a table lock within the transaction, if not, is it because doing so will break the consistency of the transaction?